# Suppress deprecated numpy API warning from `cython.inline`

Tags: python, numpy, cython

When I run `cython.inline` with a numpy argument, the compiler spits out a numpy deprecation warning. Example:

```
import cython
import numpy

y = numpy.zeros((1, ))
print(cython.inline('x = y + 1', quiet=True, force=True)['x'])
```

Output (Python 3.5.2, Cython 0.27.3, numpy 1.13.3):

```
In file included from /Users/alex/Library/Caches/cython/inline/_cython_inline_71247e2c4c276ce71de47a12a21f4fd3.c:504:
In file included from /Users/alex/.virtualenvs/pysb3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/alex/.virtualenvs/pysb3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:
In file included from /Users/alex/.virtualenvs/pysb3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:
/Users/alex/.virtualenvs/pysb3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
 ^
1 warning generated.
[ 1.]
```

I'm having trouble suppressing this warning. The [cython docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build) state that the warning is normal and not anything to worry about, but my application compiles lots of code with `cython.inline` and the warnings might obscure real errors and confuse new users.

I've tried suppressing the warning with a distutils declaration, which doesn't seem to work.

```
cython.inline('# distutils: define_macros = NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API '
              'NPY_1_7_API_VERSION\n'
              'x = y + 1',
              quiet=True, force=True)
```

**How do I suppress the deprecation warning from `cython.inline`?**